# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.Character$UnicodeScript"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext

Trying to use iText7 on Android Studio, I get the following error message:

`Didn't find class "java.lang.Character$UnicodeScript" on path: DexPathList`

when reaching the line `document.add(new Paragraph("hello"));`

In the below code

```
public void CreatePDF () throws IOException{

    File file_pdf  = new File("_TEST.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_pdf);

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    document.add(new Paragraph("hello"));

    document.close();
}
```

I have included the followings in \libs :

itext7-io-7.0.1.jar

itext7-kernel-7.0.1.jar

itext7-layout-7.0.1.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar

slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar

and following dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but we haven't released an Android version of iText 7 yet.

Answer (score 3):

**The official answer:**

iText 7 requires Java 7. The error tells you that the class `Character.UnicodeScript` is missing. When you check the API documentation, you discover that this class was introduce in Java version 1.7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html (look for **Since:** on that page). I assume that your Android setup uses a version of the Dalvik system that isn't compatible with Java 7. The class `Character.UnicodeScript` isn't present on your Android setup.

**An additional remark for your info:**

As Amedee indicated, there is no Android port for iText 7, and we probably won't make such a port because we hardly sell any iTextG (or "iText for Android") licenses, so I guess your only option is to use iTextG, which is the Android port of iText 5.

Many developers don't understand that using AGPL software implies that all the software using iText has to be AGPL only, and that the moment you distribute the software under any other license (e.g. a commercial license) requires purchasing a commercial license with iText software. The sales for this or that product are important for iText Group to define the technical road map. The poor sales number for iTextG along with the fact that we hardly find any AGPL Android projects in which iTextG is used under the AGPL, resulted in a very low priority for iText on Android.

I'm adding this information in case you were planning to post a follow-up question asking us why we don't provide an Android port for iText 7.